# The Apache error log may have more information ...

Tags: apache, certbot

I'm trying to install SSL certificate thanks to CERTBOT, but somehow i can't restart apache or run "apachectl configtest".

Here's what i got:

> Blockquote
>   AH00526: Syntax error on line 42 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/DLI-le-ssl.fr.conf:
>   Invalid command '41,14', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
>   Action 'configtest' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.

Indeed my /var/log/apache2/error.log file exists but is empty and here is my virtualhost conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName debout-les-idees.fr
ServerAlias www.debout-les-idees.fr

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName debout-les-idees.fr
ServerAlias www.debout-les-idees.fr

DocumentRoot /var/www/DLI.fr/public

<Directory /var/www/DLI.fr/public>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/debout-les-idees.fr/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/debout-les-idees.fr/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/debout-les-idees.fr/chain.pem
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/DLI.fr_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/DLI.fr_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anybody knows what's wrong with my configuration?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong here:

the name of the error.log file was wrong i had to put

```
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.debout-les-idees.fr-error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.debout-les-idees.fr-access.log combined
```

instead of

```
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/DLI.fr_error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/DLI.fr_access.log combined
```

since my domain is "debout-les-idees.fr" and not "DLI.fr"